# I am creating a dictionary in google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a newbie in coding.
I am trying to create a function in google app script that acts like a dictionary and pulls out the meaning of the word passed as the argument. Its using the API of oxford dictionaries but its not working.  Its showing the error 403. "var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,headers);" shows the error.

```
function Word_meaning(word){ 
    var url="https://odapi.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/en/" + word + "/regions=us";
    var headers =
    {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'app_id': 'abc',
        'app_key': '123'
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,headers);
    var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details about the issue you are having and the desired outcome. Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have elaborated the details. Kindly advice.

Comment: Advise you on what? How to use the Oxford API? Have you looked at their API documentation? It will tell you how to connect and authenticate. Also consider reading documentation on `UrlFetchApp` to make sure you are specifying your optional parameters correctly. You can build the request before sending it, and thus verify that it is constructed as you expect it to be. This simple debugging is your requirement **before** asking questions...

Comment: Apologies for the same and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things - why do you include the port number in the API call? My API endpoint for querying Oxford Dictionaries looks different. Also, there's a dash in "od-api".

```
https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/{word_id}/regions={region}
```

Testing the link in the address bar, I get the expected server response of "Authorization required" while the URL you provided doesn't seem to exist.

Anyway, the error pops up because the optional 'params' object for the **UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)** method is not constructed properly. The "headers" property must be contained within that object.  Somewhat ambiguous here, but please read:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)

I was able to get things up and running using the code below.

```
function getData(word, region){

  var word = word || "leprechaun";
  var region = region || "us";
  var wordId = encodeURI(word);
  var baseUrl = "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/{word_id}/regions={region}";
  var app_id = "app_id";
  var app_key = "app_key";

  var headers = { 
                  "app_id": app_id, 
                  "app_key": app_key
                 };

  var options = { 
        "headers": headers, 
         "muteHttpExceptions": true 
          };

  var url = baseUrl.replace("{word_id}", wordId)
                   .replace("{region}", region);


  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var responseCode = res.getResponseCode();


  if (responseCode == 200) {

    var data = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());

  } else {

    Logger.log(res.getContentText());


  }


}
```