# Is there a script or function on Google Sheets that will input a word and output all definitions from an online dictionary (eg merriamwebster)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've tried the function IMPORTXML
my code:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/*C2*","getElementsByTagName(name)[0];y = x.childNodes[0];z = y.nodeValue", "en_US")
```

C2 is a placeholder for cell name

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738906/i-am-creating-a-dictionary-in-google-spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`"https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/*C2*"`

use

`"https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/"&C2`

Comment: I am using that but it is still not working for many words that the site I am using has definitions for

Comment: @SarkarOffspring Please post a new question providing the formula that you tried as well some sample data including words that works as well other that doesn't.

Comment: I have posted a new question with different code